# How to expose beans as attributes through application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot

consider the following bean:

```
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver() {
    final InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
    return resolver;
}
```

How can I reproduce `setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true)` through application.properties?

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
....
```

Comment: Getting the boolean value from the properties isn't an option? If I understood correctly, effectly it would have the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create Spring boot Configuration Properties.

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.mvc.view")
public class SpringMvcViewProperties {

    private String prefix;

    private String suffix;

    private boolean exposeContext;

    public String getPrefix() {
        return prefix;
    }

    public void setPrefix(String prefix) {
        this.prefix = prefix;
    }

    public String getSuffix() {
        return suffix;
    }

    public void setSuffix(String suffix) {
        this.suffix = suffix;
    }

    public boolean isExposeContext() {
        return exposeContext;
    }

    public void setExposeContext(boolean exposeContext) {
        this.exposeContext = exposeContext;
    }
}
```

Then use that configuration Properties like

```
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver(SpringMvcViewProperties viewProps) {
    final InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix(viewProps.getPrefix());
    resolver.setSuffix(viewProps.getSuffix());
    resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(viewProps.isExposeContext());
    return resolver;
}


// application.properties
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
spring.mvn.view.exposeContext=true
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. At the end it looks like setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes() can not be set directly with application.properties. (at least not without writing even more code) As my initial goal was to use less code by leveraging application.properties, I will stay with my Bean as it is now I guess.

Comment: @yglodt You could use `@Value("spring.mvc.view.exposeContext")`.